# XSLT transformation: Substring after a last special character

Tags: xslt

I have fields "commercial register code: 1111111" and "commercial register code 2222" I need to take after last space symbols: 1111111 and 2222. There is function to take symbolrs before "space" in xsl?

Regards

**Update from comments**

> I will have "comercial register 21
>   code:" line

And

> "code" can be without ":" symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is going to be one and only one number, then you could use

```
translate($string,transtale($string,'0123456789',''),'')
```

This will remove any not digit character from the string.

If the prefixed label is stable, then you could use something like:

```
substring-after($string,'commercial register code:')
```

Abour the question:

```
There is function to take symbolrs before "space" in xsl?
```

Answer: Yes, [`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before) function

**Update**

From comments, it looks like the string pattern would be:

```
'commercial register' number 'code' (':')? number
```

Then use:

```
translate(substring-after($string,'code'), ': ', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if i will have "comercial register 21 code:" line, then will take and "21" with translate function...

Comment: "Answer: Yes, string-before() function" I think you mean substring-before()?

Comment: @Arunas: Then you should provide a useful example. If all the labels have the form `comercial register ## code:`, then use `substring-after($string,'code:')`

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, your answers was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, use `tokenize($in, '\s+')[last()]`

If you're stuck with 1.0, you need a recursive template: check out str:tokenize in the EXSLT library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use EXSLT functions? If so, there is a [str:split](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html) function and then you can do:

```
str:split($string, ' ')[position()=last()]
```